# Logstash opensearch output no getting document_id

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, opensearch

I am trying to transfer data between two opensearch instances using:

```
input {
    opensearch {
        hosts =>  ["http://192.168.1.245:8443"]
        index =>  "crawl"
        query =>  '{ "query": { "match_all": {}} }'
    }
}

output {
  opensearch {
    hosts => ["http://192.168.1.245:9200"]
    index => "crawl"
    document_id => "%{[id]}"
    doc_as_upsert => true 
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
}
```

The problem I have is that it is not inserting the the input document_id into the output document_id:

I tried:

```
document_id => "%{[id]}"
document_id => "%{id}"
document_id => "%{[_id]}"
document_id => "%{_id}"
document_id => "%{[document_id]}"
document_id => "%{document_id}"
document_id => "%{[metadata][id]}"
```

it saves it into the index as the lookup:

```
"_index": "crawl",
"_id": "%{document_id}",
"_score": 1.0,
```

Anybody have some ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this:

- Add `docinfo => true` in your input
- Find the `_id` of the document in the `[@metadata][_id]` field

Config:

```
input {
    opensearch {
        hosts =>  ["http://192.168.1.245:8443"]
        index =>  "crawl"
        query =>  '{ "query": { "match_all": {}} }'
        docinfo => true                           <----------
    }
}

output {
  opensearch {
    hosts => ["http://192.168.1.245:9200"]
    index => "crawl"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][input][opensearch][_id]}"          <----------
    doc_as_upsert => true 
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
}
```

Comment: I could kiss you right now. Your solution didn't work but you pointed me in the right direction to get it to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, the [default docinfo_target](https://github.com/opensearch-project/logstash-input-opensearch/blob/main/lib/logstash/inputs/opensearch.rb#L120-L137) is `[@metadata][input][opensearch]`, my fault sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the advise given by Val I managed to get it to work with the following:

```html
input {
    opensearch {
        hosts =>  ["http://192.168.1.245:8443"]
        index =>  "crawl"
        query =>  '{ "query": { "match_all": {}} }'
        docinfo => true <----
        docinfo_target => "[@metadata][doc]" <----
    }
}

output {
  opensearch {
    hosts => ["http://192.168.1.245:9200"]
    index => "crawl"
    document_id => "%{[@metadata][doc][_id]}" <----
    doc_as_upsert => true 
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }
}
```